# bad input shape error while using one hot encoding for categorical data using python

Tags: python

I am trying to one hot encode my data due to the RandomForestRegressor not being able to deal with categorical data. This is the first time i am using this technique. The code upon execution is throwing a bad input shape error. Can anyone explain how to correct this error and whether my usage of one hot encoding is correct or not.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
file='file:///F:/Download sort required/train.csv'
data=pd.read_csv(file)
data.dropna(axis=0,subset=['SalePrice'],inplace=True)
y=data.SalePrice
predictors=['LotArea','OverallQual','GrLivArea','GarageCars','TotRmsAbvGrd']
One_hot_encoded_predictors=['Neighborhood','HouseStyle','YearBuilt','ExterQual','KitchenQual']
X_numerical=data[predictors]
label_encoder=LabelEncoder()
label_encoded_cat_data=data[One_hot_encoded_predictors].apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
one_hot_encoder=OneHotEncoder(sparse=True)
X_hot_encoded=label_encoded_cat_data.apply(one_hot_encoder.fit_transform)
X=pd.concat([X_numerical,X_hot_encoded])
X_train,X_val,y_train,y_val=train_test_split(X,y,random_state=0)
model=RandomForestRegressor()
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
predictions=model.predict(X_val)
print(mean_absolute_error(y_val,predictions))
```

[This is how the sample data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66dXf.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message you have to encode the catagorical value in 1d form and then concatinate it